# How to use xcopy to copy files from a compressed NTFS folder to the root of a FAT32 volume?

Tags: compression, fat32, xcopy

I am having problems using XCOPY to copy folders and files from a compressed NTFS folder to the root of a FAT32 volume (actually a USB drive).
This looks like a Windows or Xcopy bug to me. The command works when copying to a folder on the FAT32 volume, just not when copying to the root.
The command works if a standard non-compressed folder is the source folder.
The /herky switch can be omitted and I still get an error.

```
L:\e2b\Update agFM>dir %TEMP%\ventoy
 Volume in drive C is HDD0 SSD 500GB
 Volume Serial Number is 4837-AFF5

 Directory of C:\temp\compressed\ventoy

20/10/2022  09:20    <DIR>          .
20/10/2022  09:20    <DIR>          ..
13/06/2021  12:29    <DIR>          EFI
13/09/2022  16:36    <DIR>          grub
13/09/2022  16:36    <DIR>          tool
13/09/2022  16:35    <DIR>          ventoy
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  38,648,127,488 bytes free

L:\e2b\Update agFM>xcopy /herky C:\temp\compressed\ventoy\EFI L:\EFI
C:\temp\compressed\ventoy\EFI\BOOT\bootaa64.efi
C:\temp\compressed\ventoy\EFI\BOOT\bootmips.efi
C:\temp\compressed\ventoy\EFI\BOOT\ventoyia32.efi
C:\temp\compressed\ventoy\EFI\BOOT\ventoyx64.efi
4 File(s) copied

L:\e2b\Update agFM>xcopy /herky C:\temp\compressed\ventoy L:\
File creation error - The parameter is incorrect.

Unable to create directory - L:\
0 File(s) copied

L:\e2b\Update agFM>copy  C:\temp\compressed\ventoy\efi\BOOT\bootaa64.efi l:\
        1 file(s) copied.

L:\e2b\Update agFM>del l:\bootaa64.efi

L:\e2b\Update agFM>
```

Comment: P.S. It seems the command works if I add a \  so
xcopy /herky C:\temp\compressed\ventoy\ L:\
works.
But xcopy /herky C:\temp\compressed\ventoy L:\   works if the source is non-compressed but does not work if the source is a compressed folder.

Comment: I forgot to say that the original command without the \ at the end of the source path works if the destination is an NTFS volume. So the destination volume must be a non-NTFS volume.

Comment: Root of a disk is a special case with very special obscure permissions. And there is also a difference between a removable disk (USB drive) and non-removable disk. I would expect xcopy source\*.* L:\  to work as long as you keep the /K flag out of it. Not all attributes can be copied if your target is NOT NTFS which may be part of the issue.

Comment: Yes, but it is strange that the same command works fine if the *source* folder is a non-compressed NTFS folder.

Comment: source\\*.* works even with /K.